# What is the location of the DCIM folder in the internal storage on a Xiaomi Redmi 4X?

Tags: adb, photos

I would like to make adb pull but I'm not able to locate this folder. I suppose it's in the /data folder but it says Permission denied. Somewhere I read if I try the full path it might work. Thank you.

Comment: Try 'storage/sdcard0/DCIM/'

Comment: @GadgetGuru adb shell ls storage/sdcard0/DCIM
ls: storage/sdcard0/DCIM: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's /storage/emulated/0/Dcim/

Comment: This definitely shows photos from internal storage. I wonder why I see same files if I run `adb shell ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera` in theory I should not see photos from internal storage.

Answer (score 3):

should be `storage/sdcard0/DCIM`